# Hiding WebParts programatically does not work

Tags: development, web-part

I am using the following code to hide all WebParts in a page.

```
string siteUrl = "http://site";
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl);
SPWeb web;
web = site.RootWeb;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = null;
mgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("pages/test.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.User);
mgr.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in mgr.WebParts)
        {
            wp.Hidden = true;
            mgr.SaveChanges(wp);
        }
web.Dispose();
site.Dispose();
```

Test Page has a Content Editor WebPart, Few List View WebParts and a Custom Webparts. Code runs without any errors but does not hide the Content Editor WebPart and Custom Webpart.

I am running this code in a Sharepoint 2010 installation. Any ideas?

**Note:**

1. I am not able to hide them using Web Interface as well.
2. I am able to change other properties like Title using code and it works perfectly fine for all thr Web Parts.
3. This code works if the user is given Full Permission for the whole site (I am expecting it to work when the user is given contribute permission for the page alone)This code used to work in MOSS 2007 and the user was given contribute permission for this page alone.

Comment: not related to question, but remember to dispose your SPSite and your SPLimitedWebPartManager :-)

Comment: and possibly set "web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;"?

Comment: @Anders I was about to add a disclaimer about it ;-) This is not the final code. Its a sample from the main module.

Comment: @Mauro we have that line of code in our main module.

Comment: @Mauro and hopefully set it back to true in a try/finally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly got it working. Had to change Web Part Security to fix it. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: If this is the solution mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Toni ... experience with SO! I cant mark it as answer before 16 hours from posting :)

Comment: I know :(((((((

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for [AllowHide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.allowhide.aspx) property? :)

**Update**: I was able to hide a ContentEditorWebPart in my SharePoint 2010 environment. Maybe this may help you, here is the full list of properties of the webpart.

```
ContentLink                        :
Content                            : Content
PartStorage                        :
ContentHasToken                    : False
Title                              : Content Editor
FrameType                          : Default
SuppressWebPartChrome              : False
Description                        : Allows authors to enter rich text content.
IsIncluded                         : True
ZoneID                             : Left
PartOrder                          : 0
FrameState                         : Normal
Height                             :
Width                              :
AllowRemove                        : True
AllowZoneChange                    : True
AllowMinimize                      : True
AllowConnect                       : True
AllowEdit                          : True
AllowHide                          : True
IsVisible                          : True
Hidden                             : False
CatalogIconImageUrl                : /_layouts/images/mscontl.gif
TitleIconImageUrl                  :
TitleUrl                           :
DetailLink                         :
HelpUrl                            :
HelpLink                           :
HelpMode                           : Modeless
Dir                                : Default
PartImageSmall                     :
MissingAssembly                    : Cannot import this Web Part.
ImportErrorMessage                 : Cannot import this Web Part.
PartImageLarge                     : /_layouts/images/mscontl.gif
IsIncludedFilter                   :
AuthorizationFilter                :
ExportControlledProperties         : True
ConnectionID                       : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ID                                 : g_7762e716_abae_47f1_a4f6_fcafe0411f83
StorageKey                         : 7762e716-abae-47f1-a4f6-fcafe0411f83
Connections                        :
UnknownXmlElements                 : {}
SerializedAttachedPropertiesShared :
SerializedAttachedPropertiesUser   :
CssStyleSheet                      :
UseDefaultStyles                   : True
Qualifier                          :
ClientName                         : varPart
Caption                            :
Subtitle                           :
Permissions                        : PersonalProperties
BrowserDesignMode                  : False
EffectiveTitle                     : Content Editor
EffectiveStorage                   : Personal
EffectiveFrameType                 : Standard
AllowClose                         : True
ChromeState                        : Normal
ChromeType                         : Default
ConnectErrorMessage                :
Direction                          : NotSet
DisplayTitle                       : Content Editor
ExportMode                         : All
HasUserData                        : True
HasSharedData                      : False
IsClosed                           : False
IsShared                           : True
IsStandalone                       : False
IsStatic                           : False
Verbs                              : {}
WebBrowsableObject                 : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentE
                                     ditorWebPart
Zone                               :
ZoneIndex                          : 0
Controls                           : {}
BackImageUrl                       :
DefaultButton                      :
GroupingText                       :
HorizontalAlign                    : NotSet
ScrollBars                         : None
Wrap                               : True
AccessKey                          :
Attributes                         : System.Web.UI.AttributeCollection
BackColor                          : Color [Empty]
BorderColor                        : Color [Empty]
BorderWidth                        :
BorderStyle                        : NotSet
ControlStyle                       : System.Web.UI.WebControls.PanelStyle
ControlStyleCreated                : True
CssClass                           :
Style                              : System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection
Enabled                            : True
EnableTheming                      : True
Font                               :
ForeColor                          : Color [Empty]
HasAttributes                      : False
SkinID                             :
TabIndex                           : 0
ToolTip                            :
ClientID                           : g_7762e716_abae_47f1_a4f6_fcafe0411f83
EnableViewState                    : True
NamingContainer                    :
BindingContainer                   :
Page                               :
TemplateControl                    :
Parent                             :
TemplateSourceDirectory            :
AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory :
Site                               :
Visible                            : True
UniqueID                           : g_7762e716_abae_47f1_a4f6_fcafe0411f83
```

And here is the PowerShell code I used (it's actually similar to yours C#, I don't see any difference, as soon PowerShell simply calls SharePoint object model):

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$wpm = $w.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::User);

$wpm.WebParts[3].Hidden = $true
$wpm.SaveChanges($wpm.Webparts[3]);
```

Comment: AllowHide is set as True. I did this when I added the WebPart manually. Let me check this via code as well. I am breaking my head with this issue for the past 2 days. :-) Thanks

Comment: Update : Just for the heck of it I set this property via code and then hid the WebPart but it does not work :(

Comment: I've just hidden ContentEditorWebPart in my own SharePoint 2010 environment, using your code. I think, something is wrong with your webpart. Could you please paste here all the properties values (you can grab them from PowerShell, for example)? Or maybe try to add a blank new ContentEditorWebPart and try to hide it?

Comment: I updated my answer with full list of properties of my webpart. Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks omlin I am going to try this... Did the user have full permission for the site or just the page?

Comment: I'm working from PowerShell, so I'm the universe-admin here :) This could be shared-personal issue, really, I was thinking about this. Btw, you can check this, running all of your code with elevated privilegies - just for test, of course.

Comment: Tried that as well ;-) I am trying to hide a webpart for the user alone. Running code with Elevated previleages did not work as well.

Comment: If elevated privilegies don't help, so that is not a permission issue, most likely. From where do you run your code? Is it something like a button `Hide all webparts` on the page?

Comment: We have widgets (Custom webparts) and a webpage to manage these widgets. This page displays the list of widgets and users choose the widgets they want to be displayed in their home page. We manage this show/hide widgets using custom code in usercontrol.

Comment: Also it works if the user is given contribute permission for the entire site. It does not work if the user is given contribute permission for the page alone.

Comment: Ok, got it. Will try to recreate your environment a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code on a Publishing Site? Try running it on a non-publishing site.

I wonder if it's related to check-in / versioning of publishing pages.